# Selenium selector to get radiobutton text

Tags: java, radio-button, selenium-webdriver

i have a mark-up similar to the one below.

```
<div id="food-group">
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="Milk"> Cow-Milk<br>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="Cheese"> Cheddar-Cheese
<div>
```

And I need to get the label after each input (Cow-Milk, Cheddar-Cheese), using using Selenium WebDriver in Java.
I can get the components(and iterate over them) like this:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath([//div[@id='food-group']/input[@type='radio')).
```

but i can't find a way to get the text.

Comment: If you are allowed to modify the generated markup, I would highly suggest to add id's on your inputs and putting your labels inside actual `<label for="id">`. This would make it more semantically correct, and very easy to match with Selenium.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't modify the markup

Answer (score 0):

Input element's have two types of "text" property. In your example:

```
 <input type="radio" name="food" value="Milk"> Cow-Milk<br>
```

to get "Milk", you'd do:

```
getAttribute("value");
```

to get "Cow-Milk", you'd do:

```
getText();
```

Comment: On other tags `getText()` works great, but on input it doesn't, but in the end i was able to modify the markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use 

    List<WebElements> myElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath([//div[@id='food-group']/input));

for(WebElement e : myElements) {
        String textValue = e.getAttribute("value");
        if(textValue.equals("Milk"){
          return el.getText();
        }
        else if(textValue.equals("Butter") {
          return el.getText();
        }
        else if(textValue.equals("Cheese") {
          return el.getText();
        }
    }
```